# Javascript syntax - triple quotes in a single line

Tags: javascript

Following my code:

```
<div onclick="this.innerHTML='<div onclick=\"<img src=/*how to do here?*//>\">abc</div>'">a</div>
```

I would like to do everything on one line, can I specify the address of the image with the current example code or not?

Comment: Why?! That's just awful!

Comment: Quoteception....gahhh my head.

Comment: You appear to be trying to assign an HTML literal to the `onclick` event... ?

Comment: Also if you're generating a lot of HTML dynamically, you should look into using one of the many available JavaScript template systems. They're generally very yet they provide a much nicer way to do this stuff.

Comment: @MikeEdwards: no the OP is not. He's assinging JS code to the onclick event, which assigns a HTML literal to the `innerHTML` property of the element -- which is perfectly legal but causes a lot of headache due to quoteception.

Comment: I see that part, but the value that he is assigning _to_ the `.innerHTML` property contains a `div` with an `onclick` handler that appears to be literal HTML, not script `"onclick=\"<img..."`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&quot;` to represent a `"` character in an HTML attribute value delimited with `"` characters.

(Use `&amp;` to represent a `&` character in an HTML attribute value, so if you want to nest insanely then: `&amp;quot;`)

---

But don't do this.

Writing everything on a single line in not a virtue.

Writing JS in an `onclick` attribute instead of a .js file is not a good thing.

Use `addEventListener` and friends.